# ZeroBrane's Analyze: "unknown global variable" on library objects

Tags: lua, marmalade, zerobrane, marmalade-quick

I started using Project / Analyze in ZeroBrane Studio for a Marmalade Quick project and i find it quite useful getting me straight on global vs local scopes.

Here is an annoyance though: it points at the libraries - basically - as undefined globals:

```
.../resources/main.lua(11): first use of unknown global variable 'system'
.../resources/main.lua(12): first use of unknown global variable 'json'
.../resources/main.lua(13): first use of unknown global variable 'device'
.../resources/main.lua(14): first use of unknown global variable 'physics'
.../resources/main.lua(15): first use of unknown global variable 'color'
.../resources/main.lua(16): first use of unknown global variable 'director'
.../resources/main.lua(17): first use of unknown global variable 'key'
```

Is there a way to suppress the warnings for the libraries (or for particular variable names)?

As partial step I started putting this in the file beginning - it doesn't solve the complaints, just lifts them on top:

```
local system = system
local json = json
local device = device
local physics = physics
local color = color
local director = director
local key = key
```

BTW any idea if this affects performance? It seems i am converting global `director` to a local `director`, which in theory is faster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a way to turn the warnings off on particular variables at the moment, but there is a workaround you can use to suppress the warnings. Instead of `local director = director`, you can use `local director = _G.director` or `local director = rawget(_G, "director")`.

In terms of the faster access, yes using locals is faster than table access (see page 3 of [Lua performance tips](http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf)), but you likely need to run a large number of calls in a loop to see the difference. Note that LuaJIT does [its own optimization](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/table-access-performance-in-loops), which may change the performance impact.

Comment: Did not know of _G, thanks! The `_G.` trick works great for me. I.e. i'll do `local director = G_.director` and so on in the beginning, that takes care of these complaints and now i can focus on my variables only. I'll treat it as an "import" boilerplate contract between me and the Analyzer :)